# JS / JQuery / PHP / image wont update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hey guys I have a bit of a problem.

I'am in the middle of writing a profile page for a social network.
Images are uploaded, and so far I have implemented a delete image button.
When that button is clicked, ajax tells the php server which file on the web server needs to be deleted. That file gets successfully deleted server side.
When I upload a new image to the same file name, the old deleted image appears client side that used to go by the same name.

The wrong images load client side compared to what is uploaded server side.
The problem is so confusing I dont even know which to show you guys... the code for deleting the images, or the code for uploading them.
The funny thing is, if I wait a while, the correct images will be displayed.
There seems to be a huge delay in things being updated.

I want to make it like facebook, where I can delete profile images without refreshing the page and it removes the exact image I deleted, without me having to wait to see the changes. Also, if I delete images and re-upload new ones, I want to see the images I've re-uploaded. Not the old images.

Please help??

here is the code for the profile box on the main image:

```
<div id="profilebox" style="margin-top: 50px;" class="col-md-3">

    <?php $path = "images/accounts/$username/1.jpg";

        if(file_exists($path))
        {
            echo "<img  style=\"max-height: 200px; max-width: 300px;\" class=\"col-md-12\" src=\"$path\" />";   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<img  style=\"\" class=\"col-md-12\" src=\"images/img_placeholder.png\" />";
        }

    ?>








</div>
```

here is the code for the upload section on the main page

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;" class="col-xs-12">Upload photos</h1>

            <form id="upimage" action="member.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <input class="" type="file" name="image">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger cancel">Cancel</button>

                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
                </div>


            </form>
        </div>
```

server side code to handle the upload:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$count = 1;

$tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext =  end((explode(".", $filename)));


$path = "../images/accounts/".$username."/".$count.".jpg";


if(file_exists($path)) 
{
    while(file_exists($path))
    {
        $count++;
        $path = "../images/accounts/".$username."/".$count.".jpg";
    }


    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $path);



}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $path);

}






?>
```

also got this script at the bottom of php page.

```
<script>




$('#upimage').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);



    uploadImage($form);



});


function uploadImage($form)
{
    $form.find('.progress-bar')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-danger');        

    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //form element
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){

        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
        $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');   


    });

    //request completed load event
    request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
        $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html("Upload Complete!");


        setTimeout(function (){

         //something you want delayed

         window.location.reload(true); 


     }, 2000); // how long do you want the delay to be? 



        });





    request.open('post', 'sections/server.php');
    request.send(formdata); 

    $form.on('click','.cancel', function(e){ 
        request.abort();

        $form.find('.progress-bar')
            .addClass('progress-bar-danger')
            .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
            .html('Upload Aborted.');   





    });


}


</script>
```

I can also include delete code later.... just not sure where the problem is

Comment: probably a cached image. if the url doesn't change, the browser's free to used cached copies.

Comment: So I see from other posts, but I still cant figure out how to programmatically fix this. I dont want to do the whole "add random string to end of filename" thing because I have the images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ... etc. for a reason.

Comment: youd on't have to change the filename, just the url. even something like `http://example.com/kittens.jpg?random_number_here` will do. it's the URL itself that has to change, not the filename.

Comment: I honestly dont know how to do that in my case.
Any chance you can teamviewer me so I can show you whats going on with the code?

Comment: Just show some code about uploading images

Comment: ive included some code above.

Comment: Is any of that useful?
Problem is.... a lot of code to link as I dont know where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent browser from using cached data - add to the header of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
```

When you sure the new image is uploaded, you need to set "src" of presented image to new url - so it will update.

Comment: You should add id to your image, than insert js code into form request handler (inside  request.addEventListener('load'...) : getProfileImageById().src = new_image_url.  Just use prefered way to get your image by ID (JQuery/document.getElementById etc)

Comment: gave profile pic image an id.

   if(file_exists($path))
   {
    echo "<img id=\"mainprofilepic\"  style=\"max-height: 200px; max-width: 300px;\" class=\"col-md-12\" src=\"$path\" />"; 
   }
   else
   {
   echo "<img id=\"mainprofilepic\"  style=\"\" class=\"col-md-12\" src=\"images/img_placeholder.png\" />";
   }        
    </div> 

tried adding this line to request.addEventListener('load'...)

$("#mainprofilepic").attr("src", "/images/"+username+"/1.jpg?r="+Math.random()*1000);

didnt work. Thats why I need someone to look at my code properly. posting snippets isnt helping

Comment: I need to teamviewer someone. Code is a mix of html, css, JS/Jquery, and php spread on different pages. I need to be able to show you what im trying to do and what is going wrong. Are there any volunteers who will teamviewer with me please?

Comment: Scrap that... think i solved it.
Added timestamps to image names and weirdly enough after a few buggy attempts managed to get it sorted.

very confusing. +1 for correct answer